# How to add a loading window to a chart in sencha while it loads

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to add a loading window dialog to my chart while it gets its data, similair to a bufferRenderer in a grid, it should be a simple loading window about the same size as a loading dialog in a grid. I am just looking for something simple.

i think you should use maskElement however I do not know for sure, I just need the chart element to be hidden or greyed out.

heres my code

```
{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Charts',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'component'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'polar',
                        height: 520,
                        id: '',
                        width: '',
                        title: 'Pie Chart',
                        colors: [
                            '#115fa6',
                            '#94ae0a',
                            '#a61120',
                            '#ff8809',
                            '#ffd13e',
                            '#a61187',
                            '#24ad9a',
                            '#7c7474',
                            '#a66111'
                        ],
                        store: 'GenderStore',
                        series: [
                            {
                                type: 'pie',
                                label: {
                                    field: 'types',
                                    display: 'rotate',
                                    contrast: true,
                                    font: '12px Arial',
                                    color: '#fff'
                                },
                                xField: 'counter',
                                yField: 'types'
                            }
                        ],
                        interactions: [
                            {
                                type: 'rotate'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To mask loading components i usually use mask.

to mask a component:

```
.mask( [msg], [msgCls] )


Masks this component with a semi-opaque layer and makes the contents unavailable to clicks.


Parameters
•msg : String (optional)

A message to show in the center of the mask layer.

•msgCls : String (optional)

A CSS class name to use on the message element in the center of the layer.
```

but, if you mask manually a component you also have to unmask it when it is loaded, mask the chart on before render and unmask it on store load. when all the datas have been receved